# Find Length of longest substring with all 1's in a binary string with k queries

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, time-complexity, c++

Given a string of size n consisting of 0s and/or 1s.you have to perform **k** queries and there are **two** types of queries possible.

1. "1"(without quotes): Print length of the longest substring with all '1'.
2. "2 X"(without quotes): where X is an Integer between 1 to n.In this query, you will change character at Xth position to '1' (it is possible that the      character at ith position was already '1')

Input Format:

- First Line of input contains n and k, where n is string length and k is the number of queries.
- Next line contains a string of 0's and/or 1's of length n.
- Each of next k lines contains query of any one type (i.e 1 or 2).

Output Format: For each query of type 1, print in new line the maximum size of subarray 
       with all 1's.

```
     Example Input:                        Example Output:
     5 7                                   0
     00000                                 1
     1                                     1
     2 3                                   3
     1                                     
     2 5
     1
     2 4
     1
```

My Solution: O(k*n) (if most of the queries of type 1)

```
 if(type==1){
        int count=0, ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){  //longest len substring
            if(str[i]=='1'){
                count++;
            }else{
               ans=max(ans,count);
               count=0;
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",ans);
 }else{
        int xth;
        scanf("%d",&xth);
        str[xth-1]='1';   //update
 }
```

I am not able to figure out an efficient solution, as for 'type 1' query only solution I could think of is to iterate through string every time and maintain a "count" variable with all 1's consecutively and finally update "ans" variable when ith str becomes '0'.

I am thinking of using segment tree but don't know how to do. As required good solution should be O(k*log(n)) (doing "type1" query in log(n) time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observation**: Type 2 query can only make the longest substring of 1 longer.

Let's call a substring of 1's a *component*. For example, there are 3 components in this string

```
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

When a 0 is changed to 1, only the components to its immediate left and right will be affected. The length of the other components remains the same.

```
string: 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
size  : 3 3 3 0 0 1 0 4 4 4 4 0

update position 7 to 1 (1-index)
string: 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
size  : 3 3 3 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 0
```

Hence, all you need to do is to keep track of the size of each component and merge them when necessary. You can do so using a [Union-Find Disjoint Set](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/disjoint-set-data-structures/) data structure. You can have a variable to keep track of the size of the largest component and update its value if, after the merge, you get a larger component.